# UITextView subclass as delegate of itself

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitextview

Let's say I add a `UITextView` to my `UIView`, and I want it to change its background color each time the contents change. I can do this by becoming the delegate of the `UITextView` and implementing `textViewDidChange`.

If I am using this behavior frequently though, it makes sense to create a `UITextView` subclass, which I will call `ColorSwitchingTextView`. It should include the color-switching behavior by default, so that any `UIView` can simply add it instead of a standard `UITextView` if it wants that behavior.

How do I detect changes in the content from within my `ColorSwitchingTextView` class? I don't think I can do something like `self.delegate = self`.

In summary, how can a `UITextView` subclass know when its contents change?

EDIT
It seems I can use `self.delegate = self`, but this means that the UIViewController that uses the `ColorSwitchingTextView` can not also subscribe to the notifications. Once I use `switchingTextView.delegate = self` in the view controller, the subclass behavior no longer works. Any workarounds? I'm trying to get a custom `UITextView` that otherwise works like a regular `UITextView`.

Comment: "I don't think I can do something like self.delegate = self" why not? It should work just fine.

Comment: Well I don't get any errors or anything, but making a UITextView subclass a UITextViewDelegate seems strange - are you sure it's the correct approach? So far I can not get textViewDidChange to fire from inside ColorSwitchingTextView.

Comment: i dont think its a good idea to set an object's delegate to itself. Its not ideal even if it doesnt throw any errors. The correct way to do this is override whichever method in UITextView that calls `textViewDidChange` .. unfortunately, it seems like its private code that you cant access/get rejected for doing so.. not so sure about that last part though.. need more diggin

Comment: Yes - setting the delegate to self seems like a bad idea based on this thread http://lists.apple.com/archives/Cocoa-dev/2009/Jul/msg01406.html. Also, it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Sure it works, I do it to make UITextViews and fields with maximum line and/or character counts

Comment: It worked for me, but I don't know if it's a good idea or not.

Comment: It works, except the class that uses it can not also listen for change notifications. I will add this detail to my question, any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Do not set a text field (UITextField, UITextView, etc) delegate to itself. I have done this once and when I pressed the globe button to change the language, the App entered a method calling loop and froze. Apparently something tries to call a view controller method from the view delegate and this doesn't work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your subclass, listen for the `UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification` notification and update the background color when you receive the notification, like this:

```
/* 
 * When you initialize your class (in `initWithFrame:` and `initWithCoder:`), 
 * listen for the notification:
 */
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(myTextDidChange)
                                             name:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification
                                           object:self];

...

// Implement the method which is called when our text changes:
- (void)myTextDidChange 
{
    // Change the background color
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    // Stop listening when deallocating your class:
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: how would you do this in swift?

Comment: it's fine to use the notifications **IF YOU WANT TO**, but if you do want to use the delegate, simply do it in an enclosing view.

Comment: What do you mean with "enclosing view"? Thanks!

Comment: Swift version   `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewControllerNAME.myTextDidChange), name: UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification, object: self)`

Comment: Swift 5 version: `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myTextDidChange), name: UITextView.textDidChangeNotification, object: self)`

Answer (score 5):

Better to do it right way from the beginning.

What Apple and SOLID would suggest, is to subclass not the UITextView, **but the UIView**. In your custom UIColorTextView you will have member UITextView as subview and your UIColorTextView will be it's delegate. Further, your UIColorTextView will have it's own delegate and will pass required delegate callbacks from UITextView to it's delegate.

I had some task like this not with UITextView but with UIScrollView.

Comment: Exactly, just subclass the UIView which holds the UITextView and make a "system" - perfect.

Answer (score 2):

In your subclass, add `self` as an observer to `UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification`.

That said, I disagree with the ongoing conversation that setting `self` as the delegate is a bad idea. For this particular case, sure, but only because there's a better way (UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification).

Comment: It's simply not possible with UITextView **specifically**.  Sure, it's not a bad thing in general to delegate=self.  The solution is simple - you use an enclosing UIView as the delegate - creates a nice system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSNotificationCenter.

Set the delegate to self in the subclass (never tried this, but you said it works), then in the view controller you want to get notifications, do

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
         addObserver:self 
         selector:@selector(textFieldDidBeginEditing:) 
         name:@"TextFieldDidNotification" object:nil];
```

and in the subclass:

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self forKey:@"textField"];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TextFieldDidBeginEditingNotification" object:self userInfo:userInfo]
```

Now you can also pass any other info in the dictionary as well.

Comment: this will pass a NSNotification into -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField instead of a UITextField, which can be bad if you are expecting a UITextField as is done with normal delegate calls. Add something like this to the top of the method to correctly get the UITextField. if([textfield isKindOfClass:[NSNotification class]]){textField = textField.object}