# UITextView changing text color and border when in focus?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I want to subclass `UITextView` so when user taps on it, text inside becomes blue, alongside border.

I know how to this in view controller, i register as delegate and on these changes i change text view. But i want to encapsulate this code, and all of it to be inside custom text view.

What the events I can monitor that will enable me to do so?

Comment: This question is possibly duplicated here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336981/uitextview-subclass-as-delegate-of-itself

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `self.yourTxtVw.textColor = [UIColor blueColor]` in the `UITextView`'s delegate method `textViewDidBeginEditing:` if your `UITextVIew` is editable. Similarly you can add border in around your `UITextView` in the same method.

Thanks.