# in Objc ,how to do it elegantly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I wrote a subclass of UITextView ,to make the textView auto grow or shrink with the textView's content . **Now ,I have to  the textView's delegate to the subclass object it self** (because i have to do something in - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView)

```
@implementation AutoGrowTextViewV2

- (instancetype) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}



- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    return [self sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, MAXFLOAT)];
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

**But in practice , AutoGrowTextViewV2 always need to set it's delegate to other objects** , so I had to write textViewDidChange codes in everywhere. how can i make this simple? maybe runtime forward or something?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336981/uitextview-subclass-as-delegate-of-itself) help?

Comment: @trojanfoe yeah ~ it works ~ thanks a lot ~~~