# Subclassing UITextField with self.delegate causes app to freeze, CPU spikes to 100%

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, subclass, uitextfielddelegate

I have a subclass of `UITextField` which sets `self.delegate = self`. The subclass is used to prevent special characters being entered into a `UITextField`. At first it works fine, but after a few keys are pressed the CPU spikes to 100% and freezes the app. There is no crash log in Xcode because the app never actually crashes, it just stays frozen until I stop it. After some research, I have determined that the problem is setting the `delegate` to `self` - apparently I should make a separate `delegate` for `UITextField`? I have searched online but cannot find anything useful on how to do this.

My AcceptedCharacters subclass:

```
AcceptedCharacters.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AcceptedCharacters : UITextField <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end
```

And

```
AcceptedCharacters.m

#import "AcceptedCharacters.h"
#define ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS @" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_."

@implementation AcceptedCharacters

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    if (self) {
        self.delegate = self;
    }
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    //NSLog(@"AcceptedCharacters");
    // Restrict special characters
    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
}

@end
```

[image: Xcode CPU Report]

Similar questions I have found on stack overflow:

[Application freezes after editing custom UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815478/application-freezes-after-editing-custom-uitextfield)

[UITextField delegate jumping to 100% CPU usage and crashing upon using keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758025/uitextfield-delegate-jumping-to-100-cpu-usage-and-crashing-upon-using-keyboard)

[Why does UITextField lock up when setting itself to delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407377/why-does-uitextfield-lock-up-when-setting-itself-to-delegate)

I have read through the solutions but they are quite vague for a beginner. I would greatly appreciate someone to amend my code below or even point me in the direction of a tutorial or documentation? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I have tested this code on one of my `ViewControllers` and it works fine when conforming to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and when my textfield `delegates` are set to `self` (see snippet below).

In my `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.forenameField.delegate = self;
self.surnameField.delegate = self;
self.addLine1Field.delegate = self;
self.addLine2Field.delegate = self;
self.addLine3Field.delegate = self;
self.addLine4Field.delegate = self;
self.addLine5Field.delegate = self;
self.postcodeField.delegate = self;
self.telLandField.delegate = self;
self.telMobField.delegate = self;
self.emailField.delegate = self;
self.dobField.delegate = self;
self.niNumField.delegate = self;
```

I would rather create several subclasses of `UITextField` and call them on specific textfields rather than have a messy method like the one below.

```
#define ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS @" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_."
#define NUMBERS_ONLY @"1234567890"
#define CHARACTER_LIMIT 11
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    // Restrict special characters
    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    // Convert postcode field characters to uppercase
    if (textField == self.postcodeField) {
        [textField setText:[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:[string uppercaseString]]];
        return NO;
    }

    // Set max character limit on tel fields
    if (textField == self.telMobField || textField == self.telLandField) {
        NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:NUMBERS_ONLY] invertedSet];
        NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        return (([string isEqualToString:filtered])&&(newLength <= CHARACTER_LIMIT));
    }
    //return YES;
    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
}
```

Comment: I think this answer should describe it pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8049532/2708650 My advice to you is to simply never call `self.delegate = self` on any class for any reason. The reason to have a delegate is because the class itself is not capable of handling the state. If you are assigning `self` as the delegate, it means your class *does* handle the state.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I have read that post several times and still cannot find a solution. I could add the `textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` method to my class and assign `self.myTextField.delegate = self;` within it and it works fine, though some of my `ViewController`s have many `UITextFields` which all do different things. Rather than have an untidy `textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` method, surely it would be more efficient to call different subclasses on different textfields? Please see my updated post as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
@interface MyTextField : UITextField
- (BOOL)stringIsAcceptable:(NSString *)string inRange:(NSRange)range;
@end
@implementation MyTextField
- (BOOL)stringIsAcceptable:(NSString *)string inRange:(NSRange)range {
  NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS] invertedSet];
  NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

  return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
}
@end

@interface PostalCodeTextField : MyTextField
@end
@implementation PostalCodeTextField
- (BOOL)stringIsAcceptable:(NSString *)string inRange:(NSRange)range {
  [self setText:[self.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:[string uppercaseString]]];
  return NO;
}
@end

.. more subclasses
```

Then assign your view controller as the delegate and in your view controller:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
  if ([textField isKindOfClass:[MyTextField class]]) {
    return [(MyTextField *)textField stringIsAcceptable:string inRange:range];
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your answer, do you mean write this code on my `ViewController` class which holds the `textfields`? I don't want to call the `textField delegate` method on the actual `ViewController` class, please see my updated post, as I have already done this and the method ends up getting messy and hard to debug when there are multiple `textfields` doing different things. Or do you mean amend my `subclass` with your code? Sorry about this, I'm still just learning about subclasses and delegates, thanks.

Comment: It doesn't have to be as messy as that. I'll further expand my answer for you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have just implemented your code and it works perfectly! This is a much more elegant solution than what I was using, and now I can create as many subclasses as needed and call them on the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` `delegate` method on my `ViewController` class. I really like this solution, thanks a lot for spending your time to help me :)