# Swift TextField Method Not Called, Delegate is Set, now BAD_ACCESS Errors

Tags: swift, textfield, exc-bad-access

there are many similar questions about TextFields delegate method textfieldshouldreturn not being called, but all were solved by setting the delegate. Ive set the delegate, and also have a perfectly fine example in another project I've copied almost line for line. A print statement confirms no call is made. Whats more curious is that I set a random variable to test if I was even accessing the right object, but when I tried to access that variable, it crashed with a BAD_ACCESS error.

```
class TitleTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {


var randomElement: Bool = true

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    print("text field return pressed")

    return true
}
```

}

and here is where I'm using it

```
class EditViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: TitleTextField!


func configureView() {

    navigationItem.title = "Edit Goal"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("editor loaded")

    configureView()

    titleTextField.text = "placeholder"

    titleTextField.delegate = titleTextField
    titleTextField.delegate = titleTextField.self
    if let textField = titleTextField {

        textField.delegate = titleTextField
    }

    print("textfield delegate = \(titleTextField?.delegate)")

}
```

If listed some of the different ways I tried setting the delegate. I even conformed the viewController to UITextFieldDelegate and set the delegate to self but that didn't matter either. I added "randomVariable" to TitleTextField to make sure I was accessing the correct object, but when I used titleTextField.randomVariable = true   in viewDidLoad, I got a BAD_ACCESS crash.

Ive also double checked the storyboard connection. I even deleted the connection and IBoutlet and redid them, no difference. cleaned project etc.

Comment: Did you try restarting Xcode? Sometimes it has strange issues, and a restart seems to fix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow ok, so the problem was I hadnt set the textfield class to TitleTextField in my identity inspector. I had it programmatically set, I guess I didnt realize i had to do it in the storyboard too.

Comment: Ah, that'll get ya! I find myself running into this issue on occasion. Glad you found the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're conforming to the `UITextFieldDelegate` on your custom `TitleTextField` itself. Instead, you should conform to the protocol on your `UIViewController`, like so:

```
class EditViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: TitleTextField!


func configureView() {

    navigationItem.title = "Edit Goal"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("editor loaded")

    configureView()

    titleTextField.text = "placeholder"

    titleTextField.delegate = self

    print("textfield delegate = \(titleTextField?.delegate)")

}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    print("text field return pressed")

    return true
}
```

The purpose of the delegate is to respond to editing-related messages from the text field ([link to docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/delegate)). This means that the `UITextField` is already aware of these editing events. What you need to do is allow the class containing your custom `UITextField` to listen to the events that it is sending out. In your situation, that class is `EditViewController`. You can make `EditViewController` listen to the `UITextView`'s events by setting it as the delegate.

The reason for your BAD_ACCESS error is a memory-related issue. Your `UITextField` is calling itself infinitely through recursion. If you look through the calling stack you'll probably see it calling the same method hundreds of times. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747777/self-delegate-self-whats-wrong-in-doing-that) for more insight.

Comment: The whole purpose of my making a new class is to keep my ViewController from handling the textfield's delegate methods. I have a different project where I use the same setup im using here and it works fine.

Comment: i got rid of the delegate method and all that. just put a simple func that prints a line in the custom TextField class, it crashes with BAD ACCESS when i  try to call it. no delegates being used